# Circleci: Private git subdmodule with AWS ECR orb

Tags: git-submodules, amazon-ecs, circleci

I have the following config.yml for a circleci build which works well 
it's using the aws-ecr and aws-ecs orbs.

```
version: 2.1
    orbs:
      aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@0.0.2
      aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@0.0.3
    workflows:
      build-deploy:
        jobs:
          - aws-ecr/build_and_push_image:
              account-url: "myaccount.amazonaws.com"
              repo: "my/repo"
              region: us-east-1
              tag: "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}"
              filters:
                branches:
                  only: mybranch
```

The problem is this repo contains a .gitmodules file which pulls in a private subdmodule.
I can't seem to figure out how to override/extend the orb to run additionally circleci equivalent of

`git submodule update --init`

I have tried adding this to the dockerfile, but then i get

```
Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

note: the dockerfile builds fine locally, since local docker inject my git key automagically

I tried reconfiguring the orb job into steps also, i.e.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@0.0.2
  aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@0.0.3
workflows:
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - lb_build_and_push_image:
        steps:
          - add_ssh_keys:
              fingerprints:
                - "my:fin:ger:print"
          - aws-ecr/build_and_push_image:
              account-url: "account.amazonaws.com"
              repo: "my/repo-backend"
              region: us-east-1
              tag: "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}"
              filters:
                branches:
                  only: mybranch
```

...where fingerprint is from the 'user key' in ssh checkout keys. 
I've tried various configurations of jobs/steps.

And schema always fails with usual message of:

```
Error: ERROR IN CONFIG FILE:
[#/workflows/build-deploy/jobs/0] 0 subschemas matched instead of one
1. [#/workflows/build-deploy/jobs/0] expected type: String, found: Mapping
```

does anyone have pointers on how to proceed, what the right config might be, or just general pointers of how to move forward in troubleshooting?
any insight much appreciated.

Comment: [Cross-posted here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/private-git-subdmodule-with-aws-ecr-orb/30109). Thanks for updating both questions `:-)`.

Comment: whoops, sorry for not posting the cross-posted link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was the eventual solution. newer release of aws-ecr orb supplies commands for steps

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@4.0.1
  aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@0.0.3
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@0.1.1

jobs:
  build_and_push_image:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: "Pull Submodules"
          command: |
            git submodule init
            git submodule update --remote
      - setup_remote_docker
      - aws-ecr/build-image:
          repo: "my/repo"
          tag: "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}"
      - aws-cli/install
      - aws-ecr/ecr-login
      - aws-ecr/push-image:
          repo: "my/repo"
          tag: "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}"
```

however, this did rely on updates to aws orb, i would be interested if there was another way to solve this, assuming those steps had not been exposed as commands

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right path. How did you manage to add the SSH keys to the job? By using only this I get `Repository not found` error for the submodule.

Comment: @MarcelN. You have to add a GitHub machine user key to your CircleCI project so that it can access your other GitHub submodule repositories. By default, the deploy key it uses can only access the one repository. Follow https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/github-integration#controlling-access-via-a-machine-user to add the machine user key to your CircleCI project.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell CircleCI to checkout the submodules using [job pre-steps](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference#pre-steps-and-post-steps-requires-version-21) and setting the [aws-ecr/build-and-push-image](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-ecr#commands-build-and-push-image) checkout parameter to false. The trick is that we're doing the checkout (and submodule updating) ourselves and then telling the orb to skip that step.

You also need to set a User Key in CircleCI so that CircleCI has access to your private GitHub submodule repositories. Follow the directions in the [CircleCI Help Page](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/github-integration#controlling-access-via-a-machine-user) to add the User Key using a GitHub machine user.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@7.3.0
  aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@2.2.1
workflows:
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: mybranch
          pre-steps:
            - checkout # run checkout manually
            - run: # so that we can pull the submodules too
                name: "Pull submodules"
                command: |
                  git submodule sync --recursive
                  git submodule update --recursive --init
          checkout: false # tell the orb job not to run checkout
          repo: "my/repo-backend"
          tag: "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}"
```

This code is using aws-ecr 7.3.0 because the 8.0.0 and later has [a bug which does not like the checkout parameter](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/aws-ecr-orb/issues/206). Hopefully the bug will get fixed in the future.